# LinearLayout horizontal orientation doesn't work for RecycleView elements

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, orientation

I try to align all my recycle view elements by 2 on the etch line, but they align vertically only by one element on the line.

here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_pdf"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_pdf_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="ceva"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:padding="6dp"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result I get:
[image: Elements align veryical]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not understand the concept or a RecyclerView. A ViewHolder contains only 1 item (so the layout you've created affects only one ViewHolder, not the whole RecyclerView, You will never achieve what You want with that).

Instead, add those lines to Your RecyclerView in xml:

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
app:spanCount="2"
```

`GridLayoutManager` lays out items in a grid. `spanCount` defines how many columns will there be in that grid.

Also there is no need for a `LinearLayout` in your item layout. You should have just the `CardView` and the `TextView`.

Comment: I did how you said, and first it didn't work by changing GridLayoutManager in XML. Because I had my rv.layoutManager a LinearLayout .
But it worked after changing this from Kotlin code:
rv.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set items in recyclerview side by side in 2 columns then you have to use recyclerview grid layout manager. for example : [android-gridlayoutmanager-example](https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example)